# Large scale least squares of non symmetric and non square problems

Tags: linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a system like $b=Ax$ with an non symmetric and non square $A$ I would like to solve it having many elements in $x$ (lets say $10^7$).

There is a large amount of algorithms for symmetric problems (conjugate gradient) and square non symmetric ones (BICGstab).
But I have difficulties to find a method for both at ones.

I recently saw this artivle http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=355989 where the problem is restated as
$$\begin{pmatrix}I & A \\ A^T & -\lambda I \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}r \\x \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
with a small Tikhonov regularization weight $\lambda$ and $r$ as the residuum.

Does anyone know a better approach for this? I would like to avoid storing the data in $A$ twice.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A widely used iterative method for large scale linear least squares problems that allows for regularization if you want/need it is the LSQR algorithm of Paige and Saunders.  See
http://www.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lsqr/

Comment: I probably should have mentioned the authors of the link I posted. Its also from Paige and Saunders. :) However, thank you very much for the link! It is at least a great confirmation of that I did not found something too exotic and that this is a widely used approach.

Comment: Note that you don't actually have to store multiple copies of $A$ and $A^{T}$.  All that LSQR requires is that you be able to compute the matrix vector products $Ax$ and $A^{T}y$.  One copy of the $A$ matrix is sufficient for this.